# Media Queries not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Whenever I resize my browser, to see if my Media Queries are working, nothing happens.
Here's My code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .navbar-custom {
background-color: #8AC007;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius:0;
min-height:auto;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:#fff;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
padding-top:20px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active>
a:hover,.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #FFFFF;
    background-color:transparent;
    }

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #FFF;
color:#8AC007;
}

    .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
   color:#FFFFF;
   padding:20px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .nav .open>a, .navbar-custom .nav .open>a:hover, 
.navbar-custom .nav .open>a:focus {
background-color:transparent;
color:#FFF;
}

.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
border: 1px solid #fff;                
}

/*-- change navbar dropdown color --*/
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,.navbar-custom     .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
color:#8AC007;
}
.carousel{
position:asbolute;
top:-20px;
margin-bottom:60px;
height:100%;
}
.carousel .item {
  height: 320px;
}

.item img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-height: 100%;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
.first-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/static/osx-preview/overview/hero/image_large.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.second-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/187/cache/canyons-utah_18730_990x742.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.third-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(Website%20Pics/mountain.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.fourth-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(TheRoad.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.join{
color:#FFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
#join:hover{
color:#FFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

#Drew{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:100%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#DrewDescription{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:100%;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
z-index:10000;
color:rgba(57,196,232,1.00);
}
#Ben{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:200%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#BenDescription{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:200%;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
z-index:10000;
color:rgba(57,196,232,1.00);
}
#David{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:300%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#DavidDescription{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
top:300%;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
z-index:10000;
color:rgba(57,196,232,1.00);
}
#Tay{
position:absolute;
right:0%;
top:400%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#TayDescription{
position:absolute;
left:0%;
text-align:center;
top:400%;
font-size:150%;
z-index:10000;
color:rgba(57,196,232,1.00);
}
}
}
```

and the css i have for width greater than 500px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.navbar-custom {
background-color: #8AC007;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius:0;
min-height:auto;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
color:#fff;
padding-left:25px;
padding-right:25px;
padding-top:20px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active >
a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #FFFFF;
background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #FFF;
color:#8AC007;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
color:#FFFFF;
padding:20px;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .nav .open>a, .navbar-custom .nav .open>a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav .open>a:focus {
background-color:transparent;
color:#FFF;
}

.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
border: 1px solid #fff;                
}

/*-- change navbar dropdown color --*/
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a,.navbar-custom
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
color:#8AC007;
}
.carousel{
position:asbolute;
top:-20px;
margin-bottom:60px;
height:100%;
}
.carousel .item {
height: 600px;
}

.item img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-height: 100%;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
}
.first-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-
preview/static/osx-preview/overview/hero/image_large.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.second-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-
live/photos/000/187/cache/canyons-utah_18730_990x742.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.third-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(Website%20Pics/mountain.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.fourth-slide{
width:100%;
z-index:-1;
height:100%;
background-image:url(TheRoad.jpg);
background-size:100% 100%;
}
.join{
color:#FFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
#join:hover{
color:#FFFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
.team{
    padding:2%;
}
#Drew{
position:absolute;
left:5%;
top:760px;
height:40%;
width:20%;
border-radius:100%;
}
#DrewDescription{
position:absolute;
left:5%;
right:75%;
top:725px;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
}
#Ben{
position:absolute;
left:28%;
top:760px;
height:40%;
width:20%;
border-radius:100%;
}
#BenDescription{
position:absolute;
left:28%;
right:52%;
top:725px;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
}
#David{
position:absolute;
left:52%;
top:760px;
height:40%;
width:20%;
border-radius:100%;
}
#DavidDescription{
position:absolute;
left:52%;
right:28%;
top:725px;
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
}
#Tay{
position:absolute;
right:5%;
top:760px;
height:40%;
width:20%;
border-radius:100%;
}
#TayDescription{
position:absolute;
right:5%;
left:75%;
text-align:center;
top:725px;
font-size:150%;
}
}
}
```

Comment: You are using max-width: 500px for both of your media queries. The second one should be min-width:500px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the viewport tag in your page header:

`<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>`

And also, you'll need to change one of your media queries to read `(min-width:500px)`. It's worth considering a change to `em` (500 px = 31.25em) measurements as well, as explained in [this blog post](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/) by Lyza Gardner. It helps keep the design looking good in the case of a user zooming in or out manually in their browser.

Comment: Thanks alot! looks good

Comment: No worries, glad it's working for you.

Comment: What difference does the `meta` tag make?

Comment: The meta tag will enable the page to detect the width of the device being used, and scale the content to match. It helps stop that issue where you browse to a page on your phone/tablet and it's all zoomed out and tiny. At least, that's what I've been lead to believe by Google PageSpeed insights, who keep telling me to use it.